# An alternative way to deal with UIWebView (and Apple Store warnings) in react-native < 0.60

Tags: react-native, npm, cocoapods, npm-install

I have a problem that I can't solve: I'm doing a development that has to be with this react and react-native versions

npmPackages:
       react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3
       react-native: 0.59.9 => 0.59.9

To avoid warnings in the Apple Store by hand this works like a charm:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o-wTwf1R8606wF8VloGxccjOIdTmJC0hSYysFgasQ7g/edit

but i'm unable to do it programatically 
https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/react-native-community/react-native-webview/819/532829030
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/819

As an alternative option and until I can use a correct version of react-native ... Could anyone tell me if is possible to generate my own implementation of react-native without UIWebView libraries? Could that be possible?

I mean, i'm unable to "clean" UIWebView in the post_install executing pod install. I would like to do a npm install but without UIWebView libraries, with a customized react-native 0.59.9 implementation.

Thank you very much in advance and greetings.

UPDATE

Is possible to define a folder in the package.json file? Something like

```
"dependencies": {
    "@lingui/react": "^2.7.4",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "expo": "^27.1.1",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "lottie-react-native": "^2.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-intl": "^2.8.0",
    **"react-native": "mypath/my_0.59.9_react-native",**
```

PS It is the first time that I participate in Stackoverflow (although I have entered millions of times), I hope I have posed the question correctly.

Comment: There is an interesting discussion going on inone of  react-native-webview issues. I used to follow it when I was having the same issue but I managed to upgrade my RN version to 0.60. So I'm not sure what would be your best option. But this link will show top methods to get rid of this issue. Good luck. 
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/819

Comment: I think I know that thread by memory :-) even the hidden comments. Only solutions are given at the post_install level, which is what I can't get to work. So I was wondering how I could "tunnel" a version of react-native, if possible and in a reasonable way.

Comment: Then I have no clue how to resolve that issue. However I suggest you to upgrade your project to some version after 0.61 because that would be beneficial for you in lots of ways. It took only 1 or 2 hours for me to upgrade all my packages and react native to use  0.61.2 from 0.59.10.  My project was huge btw :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63840722/5954472

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I have done it with react-native 0.59.8 using [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package).

What you need to do is:

1. Follow the instructions to install patch-package in your project.
2. Modify the react native Objective-c code and remove the UIWebView (for 0.59.8 I simply deleted the content of RCTWebView.h, RCTWebView.m, RCTWebViewManager.h and RCTWebViewManager.m).
3. Run the patch-package utility to create the patch and commit it to your repo.

For example, here are the patches that I created for [react-native 0.59.8](https://gist.github.com/franck-nadeau/5df41670e08232c83ca068de9fac392a)

Cheers!